# Upload tracking to facebook

Tags: android, facebook, google-maps, tracking

I am developing an application in Android that makes the tracking when the user goes for a walk. I save it in his smartphone but I would like that the user would have the opportunity to upload the entire tracking to facebook. Is there any way to do this?

I'm using google maps.

Comment: Entire Tracking - In which format of data you want to share on facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via OpenGraph actions and objects, meaning that you'll have to transform your track to a `fitness.course` object as outlined in the docs below. Google Maps is not related to this.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/fitness.course/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/fitness.runs/

Comment: Thank you very much for this links I was looking how to send information to Facebook through Google Maps but you've opened my eyes.